# CausalImpact returning MissingDataError: exog contains inf or nans when trying to do causal impact model

Tags: python

I am trying to make a casual `timeseries` model with `CausalImpact`. I get an error `MissingDataError`:

```
exog contains inf or nans when trying to do causal impact model even if there are no inf or nans in my exog dataset.
```

```
## CausalImpact 패키지 활용
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

# time-series 예시 데이터 형성
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_process import ArmaProcess

# 시각화
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# 패키지
from causalimpact import CausalImpact

import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# 파일 경로
file_path = r"C:\Users\hgcho\Desktop\...\학부연구생\10주(240302~240308)\DRT 도입전후_동읍면별 버스통행량 평균\DRT도입전후_가경동_버스통행량.csv"

# 파일 읽어오기 
df = pd.read_csv(file_path, encoding='cp949')

# 원본 날짜 데이터를 저장
original_dates = df['BRDG_DD'].copy()

# 날짜 데이터를 날짜 형식으로 변환
df['BRDG_DD'] = pd.to_datetime(df['BRDG_DD'])

# 새로운 날짜 열을 생성하고, 초기값을 0으로 설정
df['new_dates'] = 0

# 2021-10-01부터 2021-10-31까지의 날짜를 1부터 31까지의 숫자로 변환
df.loc[(df['BRDG_DD'].dt.month == 10) & (df['BRDG_DD'].dt.year == 2021), 'new_dates'] = df['BRDG_DD'].dt.day

# 2023-10-01부터 2023-10-31까지의 날짜를 32부터 62까지의 숫자로 변환
df.loc[(df['BRDG_DD'].dt.month == 10) & (df['BRDG_DD'].dt.year == 2023), 'new_dates'] = df['BRDG_DD'].dt.day + 31

# 원래의 날짜 열을 수정한 날짜 열로 교체
df['BRDG_DD'] = df['new_dates']

# 수정한 날짜 열을 삭제
df = df.drop('new_dates', axis=1)

# 'ADM_GU'와 'ADM_NM' 열을 제거합니다 -> 모든 데이터가 int 여야하므로 동별 정보 데이터 삭제
df = df.drop(['COMP_NONPEAK', 'OSS_ACC_TOWN', 'Parking_Fee'], axis=1)
df = df.rename(columns={'COMP_NONPEAK.1': 'COMP_NONPEAK', 'OSS_ACC_TOWN.1': 'OSS_ACC_TOWN'})

# 독립변수 설정 - 시계열 데이터
X = df[['MAX_TEMP', 'MIN_TEMP', 'AVG_TEMP', 'AVG_CLOUD', 'AVG_RAIN', 'WEEKEND', 'HOLIDAY', 'K_HOLIDAY']]

# 종속변수 설정
y = df['BUSTRIP_VILLE']

# 날짜 설정
dates = df['BRDG_DD']

# 데이터프레임 생성
combined_df = pd.DataFrame({'dates': dates, 'X': X.values.tolist(), 'y': y}, columns=['dates', 'X', 'y'])

# 독립변수 이름 리스트 작성
X_columns = X.columns.tolist()

# Visualize data using seaborn
sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(12,8)})

# 각 독립변수에 대한 그래프 그리기
for column in X_columns:
    sns.lineplot(x=df.index, y=df[column])
    sns.lineplot(x=df.index, y=df['BUSTRIP_VILLE']/1000) # 단위 맞춰주기
    plt.axvline(x=intervention_start_date, color='red')  # 설정한 날짜로 변경합니다.
    plt.legend(labels = [column, 'BUSTRIP_VILLE'])
    plt.show()

# Set pre-period
pre_period = [1, intervention_start_date - 1]

# Set post-period
post_period = [intervention_start_date, df['BRDG_DD'].max()]

# Print out the values
print(f'The pre-period is {pre_period}')
print(f'The post-period is {post_period}')

# Calculate the pre-daily average
pre_daily_avg = df.loc[df['BRDG_DD'] < intervention_start_date]['BUSTRIP_VILLE'].mean()

# Calculate the post-daily average
post_daily_avg = df.loc[df['BRDG_DD'] >= intervention_start_date]['BUSTRIP_VILLE'].mean()

# Print out the results
print(f'The pre-treatment daily average is {pre_daily_avg}.')
print(f'The post-treatment daily average is {post_daily_avg}.')
print(f'The raw difference between the pre and the post treatment is {post_daily_avg - pre_daily_avg}.')

# int 데이터가 아닌 데이터 삭제
df_numeric = df.drop(['ADM_GU', 'ADM_NM', 'COMP_PEAK.1'], axis=1)

# BUSTRIP_VILLE 값의 단위를 1000으로 나누어줍니다.
df_numeric['BUSTRIP_VILLE'] /= 1000
df_numeric.head()

# 'BRDG_DD' 열을 인덱스로 설정합니다
df_numeric.set_index('BRDG_DD', inplace=True)

# 결측값이나 무한대값을 처리
df_numeric.dropna(inplace=True)  # 결측값이 있는 행 삭제
df_numeric.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan, inplace=True)  # 무한대값을 결측값으로 대체
df_numeric.dropna(inplace=True)  # 결측값이 있는 행 삭제

# Causal impact model 생성
impact = CausalImpact(data=df_numeric, pre_period=pre_period, post_period=post_period)

# Visualization
impact.plot()
```

```
MissingDataError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[83], line 17
     14 df_numeric.dropna(inplace=True)  # 결측값이 있는 행 삭제
     16 # Causal impact model 생성
---> 17 impact = CausalImpact(data=df_numeric, pre_period=pre_period, post_period=post_period)
     19 # Visualization
     20 impact.plot()




MissingDataError: exog contains inf or nans


exog.isna().sum()
np.isinf(exog).sum()
MAX_TEMP     0
MIN_TEMP     0
AVG_TEMP     0
AVG_CLOUD    0
AVG_RAIN     0
WEEKEND      0
HOLIDAY      0
K_HOLIDAY    0
dtype: int64
These are all of my independent variables(exog) in my dataset. I have doublechecked the fact that there is no such inf or non values in my dataset, but I always got MissingDataError: exog contains inf or nans. 
"pre_period" and "post_period" are the list of numbers that doesn't include inf or nan values, and there values are 1 to 31 and 32 to 62.
```